# Using SAPI.H - why does my program only speak the first word?

Tags: c++, windows, text-to-speech, sapi

I want to be able to type in a string into a program and use MS-SAPI to get the computer to speak that string. I'm doing it in C++. Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <sapi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::wstring str_to_ws(const std::string& s)
{
    int len;
    int slength = (int)s.length() + 1;
    len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, 0, 0);
    wchar_t* buf = new wchar_t[len];
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, buf, len);
    std::wstring r(buf);
    delete[] buf;
    return r;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    while(true) {
        std::cout << "Enter some words: " << std::endl; std::cout << ">> ";
        std::string text; std::cin >> text;
        std::cout << "" << std::endl;
        std::wstring stemp = str_to_ws(text);
        LPCWSTR speech_text = stemp.c_str();
        ISpVoice * pVoice = NULL;
        if (FAILED(::CoInitialize(NULL))) {}
        HRESULT hresult = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SpVoice, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_ISpVoice, (void **)&pVoice);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hresult)) {
        hresult = pVoice->Speak(speech_text, 0, NULL); 
        pVoice->Release();
        pVoice = NULL;
    }
    ::CoUninitialize(); 
    return TRUE;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the program only says the first word of the string and then quits...how do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The input is not being read correctly.

```
std::cin >> text;
```

stops after reading one whitespace-delimited token. If the input is "I am the very model of a modern major-general." `std::cin >> text;` will stop reading at the first space and provide only "I" in `text`. The remainder of the line stays in the stream waiting to be read.

```
std::getline(cin, text);
```

is probably more along the line of what you want. [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) will read everything up to the end of the input line using the default end of line delimiter. Other overloads of `std::getline` allow you to specify the delimiter, making it a good general purpose parsing tool.

Comment: Thanks so much! That really helped! I got it with `std::getline(std::cin, text);`